# Как сделать текст под картинкой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, делаю интеграцию. По апи получаю json и мне нужно разместить это всё на странице по принципу:
блоки заполняют экран, в каждом блоке название товара под картинкой. А выходит так, что текст рядом с картинкой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Как можно это поправить? если удаляю css То у меня текст получается под картинкой, но тогда всё идёт в один столбик[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее код:
`<div class="container"></div>`

// Получаю данные из апи

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
position.forEach((element) => {
  const item = document.createElement('div');
  item.className = 'item';
  item.innerText = element.name;
  item.innerText += " " + element.price;
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = element.src;
  img.width = 100;
  img.heigth = 100;
  container.appendChild(img);
  container.appendChild(item);

})
```

и style.css

```
.container{
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<img>` по-умолчанию имеет свойство `display: inline`, из-за чего все элементы становятся в ряд. Измени свойство на `display: block`. А вообще, настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться подробнее с этим свойством, ибо знания очень сырые.